# Cursor getString() or getInt() doesn't return the value at given index

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database and table for an Android app. Values can be inserted and long id returned with no problems. When the returned id is used to retrieve the other fields the getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME) returns the correct index, but when to use getSting and getInt to get the value of the field, the app crashes. Android studio doesn't give any errors. Please help.

Database handler class:

```
public class SqliteDBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 
private static final String DB_NAME = "baby_diary.db"

private static final String TBL_BABIES = "babies";
private static final String BABIES_BABY_ID = "baby_id";
private static final String BABIES_NAME = "name";
private static final String BABIES_DOB = "dob";
private static final String BABIES_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String BABIES_WEIGHT = "weight";
private static final String BABIES_HEIGHT = "height";
private static final String BABIES_THEME = "theme";

public SqliteDBManager(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION, errorHandler); 
    }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_TBL_BABIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_BABIES + "( " +
                BABIES_BABY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                BABIES_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                BABIES_DOB + " TEXT, " +
                BABIES_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                BABIES_WEIGHT + " REAL, " +
                BABIES_HEIGHT + " REAL, " +
                BABIES_THEME + " TEXT" + " );";

                db.execSQL(CREATE_TBL_BABIES);
    }
    public Babies getBabyById(Long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TBL_BABIES + " WHERE " + BABIES_BABY_ID
                + " = \"" + id + "\";";
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TBL_BABIES,
                null,
                BABIES_BABY_ID + " = " + id,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                //for testing getInt
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BABIES_BABY_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BABIES_NAME));
                cursor.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use cursor.moveToFirst() before querying the first row from the cursor.  Change your if statement to:

```
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

Also, the cursor has to be closed even if you have no results.  I'd recommend writing it like this:

```
try {
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst) {
            //for testing getInt
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BABIES_BABY_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BABIES_NAME));
        }
}
finally {
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

This way your cursor will be properly closed no matter what exception may occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Cursor is no data.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TBL_BABIES,
            null, //This must not null. In here your columns in string array
            BABIES_BABY_ID + " = " + id,
            null, null, null, null);
```

For example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TBL_BABIES,
            new String[]{BABIES_BABY_ID, BABIES_NAME}, //What column you need
            BABIES_BABY_ID + " = " + id,
            null, null, null, null);
```

In somecase you need to add this command inside `if` condition

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: I think null returns all fields of the row, and it seems works for me. You are right about the moveToFirst() though.